# open covers of sin x

Tags: general-topology

let P=$\{(x,sin x) \in \mathbb R^2\} $

I need to find with respect to the euclidean metric ,d.

a open cover of P that has a finite sub cover

a open cover that does not have a finite sub cover

a $d_{P}$ open cover.

for the last part I'm    thinking I can just take arcs  of the curve.

for the first one can I just take all points to the left of y axis and all points to the right of x axis so the union covers and it's finite so  I can take that as finite sub cover?

and for the second would union of   rectangles of width  one height 2  do?

Comment: What is a $\;d_P\;$ open cover?

Comment: Why do you *apparently* think that all points to the left and right of the $\;y\,-$ axis are finite?

Comment: @DonAntonio  am I  mistaken? I'm thinking a finite cover is a finite union of open sets, does it have to be the open sets are also finite?  $d_{p}$ is the metric induced by p from the euclidean metric d

Comment: First, I can't tell what "open" sets you're taking since singletons (i.e, single point sets) are *not* open in the euclidean topology. Second, even assuming you had some actually open sets, the set of points "on the left and on the right" of the $\;y\,-$ axis (no matter whether you mean on the $\;x\,-$ axis or on the whole plane) are uncountable.

Comment: @DonAntonio my idea was to use the union of the sets $\{ (x,y):x<1\}$ and $\{ (x,y):x>0\}$ which are open and cover. Are you saying these sets have to be finite to form a cover?can you suggest cover with finite subcover? do the rectangles i describe work for the othet part?

Comment: @ji Now it's clear what you meant and yes: those two sets are open and cover $\;P\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio, ok thanks. so  I'm  also to say it has a finite subcover as I  can take the whole cover? does my idea of rectangles cover without a finite subcover? I  would ensure if  I consider 3 rectangles they would overlap the middle one  and  leave a strip that entirely lies  only in the middle rectangle.

Comment: @DonAntonio  I'm still unclear on the last part. in another question I was told a straight line only had closed subsets,so  can I use arcs of the curve?are they open with respect to the induced metric $d_{p}$